# One dimensional differential equation with resonance recombination (RHS)

Tags: pde, numerical-modelling

I am trying to solve the following equation: 
$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial \epsilon}\left[B\left(\epsilon\right)f_e\left(1-f_e\right)+D\left(\epsilon\right)\dfrac{\partial f_e}{\partial \epsilon}\right] = R\left(f_e, f_h, E\right)$$

Till now, there is nothing special at all, and I can solve this (with a simple $R$).

---

But, the most important part of this equation is a form of recombination $R$:

$$R \approx \dfrac{1}{A-B\cdot f_e}$$

$A,B$ - are known constants and $(A-B\cdot f_e)$ should always be positive!

But numerical scheme which I use does not know anything about it, and it simply jumps through this boundary, which means no special recombination is included.

Typical value of $(A-B\cdot fe) \in [ 10^{-14},10^{-7}]$

Are there any methods to solve it? 
The main problem is resonance characteristic of recombination $R$.

---

I trying to change $A$ on each iteration and wait for the convergence, after change boundary parameters (which is a parameter to change exactly) and solve again. I perform this procedure until $|A - A_\text{const}| = 1e-4$.

(This method works bad because of the relaxation coefficient within Newton iteration ~ 1e-6.)

Comment: Which method are you using to solve this equation?

Comment: Do you get catastrophic cancellation in $A-Bf_e$? What method are you using, and what tolerances do you set?